# Implementing Comparator from an abstract class

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class, comparator

```
public abstract class SomeClass<Sometype extends OtherClass> extends Something   implements   Comparator<??>{

//code
```

How can I replace ?? in Comparator such that it is any class that extends SomeClass?

Comment: Do you mean `SomeClass` or `SomeType`?  Or did you mean `Comparable` instead of `Comparator`?  It really doesn't make sense to have a `Comparator` that can do comparisons on other `Comparator` objects.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to make sure that every sub-type of SomeClass will implement the CompareTo method

Comment: So if `x` and `y` are objects of some subtype of `SomeClass`, you want to be able to write `x.compareTo(y)`, is that right?  If so, you are confusing `Comparator` with `Comparable`.

Comment: Right.......What was I thinking?

Comment: So, would you now like to edit your question so that it reflects what you _really_ want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you want to carry the type-bounds or simply allow any subclass of `SomeClass`.

By definition, the `compare` method you implement will allow comparison with any subtype (because any subtype can be cast to the more general parent type when passed to the method).

To allow any parameterized type instead of the restrictive `Sometype`, you can write:

```
public abstract class SomeClass<Sometype extends OtherClass> extends Something
   implements Comparator<SomeClass<?>>
```

It's also legal to write this with explicit type bounds:

```
public abstract class SomeClass<Sometype extends OtherClass> extends Something
   implements Comparator<SomeClass<Sometype>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use something like `? extends SomeClass` , but you can use just `Comparator<SomeClass>` and cast to what you need